# Group coordinator is unavailable or invalid error in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We are observing below error on Kafka Consumer side for different topics and consumer groups

**Group coordinator is unavailable or invalid due to cause: error response REQUEST_TIMED_OUT.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted**

Below is the consumer configuration for reference.

*kafka_enable_auto_commit: "true"
kafka_auto_commit_interval: "5000"
kafka_session_timeout: "25000"
kafka_concurent_threads: "1"
kafka_poll_timeout: "3000"
kafka_max_poll_interval : "900000"
kafka_max_poll_records : "100"*

Kafka Version: 1.1.1

We tried restarting the brokers but with no luck.

Replication factor = 3
min.insync.replicas = 2

We tried restarting all the kafka brokers but we still see the issue for different kafka consumers and different group coordinators ( brokers)